# Google Play Signing: is it a problem to enroll several apps signed with the same key?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-play, google-play-console

I have on Google Play several apps in production. Until now, I don't use Google Play Signing.

As it seems that Google Play Signing is great for security and to reduce the size of the delivered apk, I would like to enroll all my apps.

The problem is that I historically always signed all of them with the same key (same keystore, same alias).

I wonder if it will be a problem for the Google Play Console. Once I enrolled one app, will I be unable to enroll the other apps? I am afraid to receive a message like this: "you can't upload the same key for several apps with Google Play Signing".

So you see any other problem that could arise from this situation?

As cancelling Google Play Signing is not possible once you enrolled, I would not like to enroll if it will induce problems... The worst problem being to be unable to update my apps!

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you should ask Google Play support if you are not able to find the answer on the internet. By the way in my opinion the worst case scenario is that you would be able to enroll only one of your app to Google Play Signing. You would continue to update the other ones as always

Comment: Thanks. By what channel should I ask this question to Google? Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, I’ve signed about 7 apps with the same key store and alias, then switched to Google Play signing for all of them without issue.

Comment: @Regis_AG Tenfour gave you a good news :)
The support should be there: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/gethelp